# Replay the hint sound

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my drag and drop game there is a grid that is populated with words that are hidden from the user. The aim of the game is to spell these words with the aid of a sound and a picture.

When the user is spelling the word they should be able to replay the sound to help them. I had it working before but it has stopped working and I cannot work out why.

Here is the code that makes it work...

```
$(".minibutton2").click(function() {
var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist) {
    $('.minibutton2').prop('disabled', true);

} else {

    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
    audio.play();
}
});
```

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/m8Squ/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable is

```
var pic = $("#mypic")[0]; // pic.show() exception
```

so; is pic.show() change jQuery(pic).show();

http://jsfiddle.net/m8Squ/9/

else and he can

```
 var pic = $("#mypic").eq(0); // pic.show() not exception..
```